# CSS not loading after redirect with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following Short-hand for a user profile url

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./profile.php?name_of_user=$1
```

The site is styled with the appropriate css file when i do `site.com/name_of_user`

but not when i do `site.com/name_of_user/`

Although the redirect is to the right page...

Help is appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is when you haven't showed us the actual HTML that calls your CSS, but I suspect it's because you're referring to the directory incorrectly in your `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 32):

the easiest way to fix this is to specify the full path to your CSS file in the `<head>` of the HTML file.

If your mod_rewrite rule is modifying the path to where your CSS file is, you'd also want to place this before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This makes sure that the request doesn't match a file before rewriting it.

Comment: +1 not only the easiest way but that also fix nested sub folders

Comment: this fixed the issue with my javascript files as well!

Comment: This worked. Thanks. And my issue may help someone else: I was redirecting from one location to another (without rewriting the url), and assuming I was at the new location when I was still at the old location. The access to the .css file had to work in the old location (and the new location too, in my circumstance).

Comment: i added this but it is still not loading my css.. why is that?

Answer (score 20):

I had this same problem and have found the easiest and most practical solution.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

It's super clean and easy to use.

Answer (score 15):

link the css files relative to the root directory
sample:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/****.css">
```

Comment: I have tried this which is working for me 
http://www.chatfitness.com/
didn't check answer2

Comment: same issue as OP; (styles were working on "site.com/aaa", but not working on "site.com/aaa/bbb"); had to change `href="css/***.css` to `href=/css/***.css`. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

When your page URL is `example.com/name_of_user/`, loading of resource css/js/images may cause problems if your HTML page is using **relative paths** for these resources. It is because browser resolves resource URLs using current URL.

So for example if a style tag is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
```

and your current page URL is:

```
http://example.com/name_of_user/
```

Then browser will resolve css URL as as `example.com/name_of_user/static/style.css` instead of `example.com/static/style.css`. This will cause 404 for resource URLs and your page will be displayed without any style, scripts and images.

You can solve this problem using one of the following ways:

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. **Otherwise** You can add this **just below** `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

   ```
   <base href="/" />
   ```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Answer (score 7):

Try to set right basedir at your html documents head section:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://example.com/">
<head>
```

Then any extra slashes (/) at your .htaccess rules won't change exterial sources path in your html documents. The following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./profile.php?name_of_user=$1
```

won't make this behaviour with `<base href="http://example.com/">` at document's `<head>`.
It will works fine, especially for relative site file structures.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /public/$1.$2 [L,NC]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, after changing the directory names as needed. Guess the only downside would be maintaining a whitelist for the first rule.
Maybe using a blacklist might be a better solution in case of media/different types of files.

Comment: This is the best answer I could find anywhere on the web. Thank you for being so specific!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This works like a treat. I originally had problem even with giving absolute linking. Thanks and +1 to Steve Lewis.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this `site.com/name_of_user/` you change the working directory on your site from `root` to `name_of_user`, therefore the relative path for each file or link on the requested page would become `/name_of_user/` instead of `/`.

To fix this you need to add additional rule to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^name_of_user/(.*)?$ $1
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `<base href="site url here">`, and this should be soon after the opening HTML `head` tag.
Site url needs to start with http or https; if you are on localhost then use http, for example

```
http://localhost/road/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had what seems to be the same problem. I was trying to redirect from a site of the form:
   www.foo/category/details.

I found the slash after "category" stopped both the CSS and images from being loaded.

The cause is the default redirection passes the original URL to the browser.  This can be seen from a JScript trace on window.location.pathname.  The solution is simply to use a [R] flag in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the base path after the opening head tag. For example:

```
<base href="website url here">
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and Simple way only add this tag in your redirected file's top of header and chill all will be right!

```
<head>
   <base href="website url here">
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I've solved it with the following code. Not the best solution but it works.

```
RewriteRule ^(something/)$ something [R] 
RewriteRule ^(something)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```