# In which folder should I store CSS files?

Tags: .htaccess

[image]

I had a php page in which CSS/js work normally.
Then I add htaccess rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)/?$ site/command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

after which page can not load CSS/js and "not found" error appear.
I did not change the folder for css/js, simply add rule.
When I open dev tools in browser, it seems like my page is parent folder and css/js files are child files, which is not normal.
I am new in php and very confused in this folder stuff. 
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please insert relevant bits of code (html/php linking js/css) and text of errors instead of the picture. Your problem seems to have nothing to do with php but rather with .htaccess, so I've removed the `php` tag. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using one of the following ways:

Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Otherwise You can add this just below  section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

[CSS not loading after redirect with htaccess rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221022/css-not-loading-after-redirect-with-htaccess-rewrite-rule)