# How to redirect my homepage only using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know this is silly question for you but not for me

I am using `rdp` for manage my account and somehow I got problem in that

Like I have my portfolio in `hthocs/portfolio` folder, now whenever someone visit it, i need like that

> example.com

and whenever someone visit `htdocs/example`, i need like this

> example.com/example

**So i only want to redirect homepage folder in my site and other folder behave regularly**

I search on internet and I found like that

> RedirectMatch ^/$ /portfolio

but using this, its shows correct path like `example.com/portfolio`

**EXAMPLE**

Give you example of `localhost`,

```
htdocs
|
|--- portfolio (folder)
|--- stackoverflow (folder)
```

Whenever I visit `localhost` in browser ( internally it will redirect to `htdocs/portfolio` ) and when I visit `localhost/stackoverflow` in browser, It will redirect to `htdocs/stackoverflow` not in `htdocs/portfolio/stackoveflow`.

using `RedirectMatch ^/$ /portfolio` this code, I solved my problem but whenever I visit `localhost`, in browser its shows real path `localhost/portfolio`. i don't want to client know it will redirect to this folder

I use `#` to scroll in website but now when i click on that, it will redirect to original folder

Comment: I don't know what `rdp` is and I find your question quite confusing, but from what I understood you want to escape from your document root (that I suppose is `/htdocs/portfolio`). AFAIK this cannot be done: you could circumvent it by using symlinks though.

Comment: rdp is remote desktop protocol, i have `aws` but i dont understand any word in your comment

Comment: You **must** know what a document root is. Please, refer to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html to highlight the differences between url and local path.

Comment: In that article, the section [Files Outside the DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside) addresses your problem.

Comment: i know what document root is but i dont want to change document root path, i want to change only homepage path and other folder behave regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to internally rewrite / to /portfolio
RewriteRule ^$ /portfolio/ [L]
```

To fix css/js, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for answer but i need both condition in one, you can see my `edit`

Comment: your 2nd solution, works fine but css js not loading

Comment: I really don't know about apache things, please visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221022/css-not-loading-after-redirect-with-htaccess-rewrite-rule

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`. To fix css/js I have suggested and answered this multiple times on stackoverflow and it definitely works.

Comment: Yes but i want to change your answer

Comment: Nice you solved your problem @StackoverflowUser using help, appreciate your help anubhava, +1 for that

Comment: I approved your edit @StackoverflowUser, and hope anubhava will also except it

Comment: Part after `#` is not even sent to web server and is kept as is after internal rewrite.

Comment: can you help my friend on that case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884652/some-url-is-redirect-to-real-destination-but-some-not-404-page-htacess-php